# Full text search jquery -highlight yellow background

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css

i have in my asp.net page a textarea where users type an article="long text" to be saved in the database. In another page i display these articles(textarea) in a :

```
  <p class="p-article">
      the text of the article goes here.

  </p>
```

I'd like to filter these articles by search keywords .for example when a user search for "Startup Marketing".

I want to apply the keywords as a filter and get articles and bring those that contain "Startup" or "Marketing" or "Startup Marketinbg".And this in client side by jquery if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This may help

```
var keyword = $("#searchtextbox").val().split(' ');
$.each(keyword,function(){
$(".p-article").html(function(index,oldhtml){
return oldhtml.replace(keyword,"<span style='background-color:Yellow'>"+keyword+"</span>");
});
});
```

Comment: this just highlight the words,how about searching for them?.Thanks anayway.